# ERROR: insert or update on table "S2" violates foreign key constraint "S2_customer_id_fkey"

Tags: database, postgresql, foreign-keys

Just making up some tables, only to find this error, i have spent over an our leering at the code but could not find the error.
Can you guys please help me with this.
Here is Query i'm typing in the editor

```
CREATE TABLE "P1"
(PRODUCT_ID INT,
PRODUCT_NAME CHAR(100),
PRODUCT_DISCOUNT INT,
PRODUCT_BRAND CHAR(100),
PRODUCT_SIZE INT,
PRODUCT_COLOR CHAR(100),
PRODUCT_SELLING_PRICE INT,
PRODUCT_PIRCHASE_PRICE INT,
PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE "C4"
(
Customer_Id int,
Customer_Name char(100),
Customer_Address varchar(255),
Customer_Phone varchar(255),
Customer_Email varchar(255),
Product_Id INT,
primary key(Customer_Id),

foreign key(Product_Id)
references P1(PRODUCT_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE "S2"
(
Department_Id int,
Department_Name char(100),
Product_Id int,
Customer_Id int,
primary key(Department_Id),
foreign key(Product_Id)
references P1(PRODUCT_ID),
foreign key(Customer_Id)
references C4(Customer_Id)
);

CREATE TABLE "E1"
(
E_Id int,
E_Name char(100),
E_Address varchar(255),
E_Email varchar(255),
Customer_Id int,
primary key(E_Id),
foreign key(Customer_Id)
references C4(Customer_Id)
);
```

On Firing the above query I get this error

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "S2" violates foreign key constraint "S2_customer_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (customer_id)=(1015) is not present in table "c4".
********** Error **********

ERROR: insert or update on table "S2" violates foreign key constraint "S2_customer_id_fkey"
SQL state: 23503
Detail: Key (customer_id)=(1015) is not present in table "c4".
```

Comment: Seems like you are trying to insert data into ```S2``` table which does not exist in ```c4``` table. But you referenced to ```c4```. In this case ```customer_id = 1015``` should present in ```c4``` table.

Answer (score 0):

you should run each query separately or use go, like this :

```
CREATE TABLE "P1"
(PRODUCT_ID INT,
PRODUCT_NAME CHAR(100),
PRODUCT_DISCOUNT INT,
PRODUCT_BRAND CHAR(100),
PRODUCT_SIZE INT,
PRODUCT_COLOR CHAR(100),
PRODUCT_SELLING_PRICE INT,
PRODUCT_PIRCHASE_PRICE INT,
PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_ID)
);
go
CREATE TABLE "C4"
(
Customer_Id int,
Customer_Name char(100),
Customer_Address varchar(255),
Customer_Phone varchar(255),
Customer_Email varchar(255),
Product_Id INT,
primary key(Customer_Id),

foreign key(Product_Id)
references P1(PRODUCT_ID)
);
go
CREATE TABLE "S2"
(
Department_Id int,
Department_Name char(100),
Product_Id int,
Customer_Id int,
primary key(Department_Id),
foreign key(Product_Id)
references P1(PRODUCT_ID),
foreign key(Customer_Id)
references C4(Customer_Id)
);
go
CREATE TABLE "E1"
(
E_Id int,
E_Name char(100),
E_Address varchar(255),
E_Email varchar(255),
Customer_Id int,
primary key(E_Id),
foreign key(Customer_Id)
references C4(Customer_Id)
);
```

Comment: Its not an answer for above question. also `go` is not required in PostgreSQL. `;` is enough for line separation.